# Installed app using apk crashes when I update my facebook sdk to 4.28.0 and up

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, facebook-sdk-4.x

When I update my facebook sdk to 4.28.0 and up then build an apk and install it in my device. The app crashes when I open it but when I run it directly using the android studio it runs fine.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-683
                                                 Process: PID: 9443
                                                 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.message.HeaderGroup.a
                                                     at org.apache.http.message.a.a(Unknown Source)
                                                     at com.android.volley.a.g.a(Unknown Source)
                                                     at com.android.volley.a.a.a(Unknown Source)
                                                     at com.android.volley.f.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: please post crash report here.

Comment: Please post your crash log, So we can help you.

Comment: already added crash log

Comment: I think you're using a method, which was removed in Facebook SDK 4.28.0. And the crash log posted here is from [Obfuscated](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html) app (using proguard) in which you can't figure out the method causing Exception.

Comment: dont copy the apk file from app/build/outputs/apk/debug (i mean drag and drop ), instead Build -> Build APK and then click locate and get the apk from there

Comment: it is the apk that has been generated from Build APK